# Running loop through multiple columns of a data set to create a new variable

Tags: r, loops, multiple-columns

I am trying to create a new variable using a loop that searches across 14 columns and returns a 1 if the string is present in any of the 14 columns and returns a 0 if it is not present in any of the 14 columns. The following code works but is quite tedious, I'm hoping someone knows of a more efficient method.

Working code:

```
IntellDis <- for (i in 1:2189){
  if(New$Diagnosis1[i]=="Intellectual disabilities [6543]" | 
     New$Diagnosis2[i]=="Intellectual disabilities [6543]" |
...
     New$Diagnosis13[i]=="Intellectual disabilities [6543]" |
     New$Diagnosis14[i]=="Intellectual disabilities [6543]")
       {New$IntellDis[i]=1}
  if(New$Diagnosis1[i]!="Intellectual disabilities [6543]" &&    
     New$Diagnosis2[i]!="Intellectual disabilities [6543]" &&
...
     New$Diagnosis13[i]!="Intellectual disabilities [6543]" &&
     New$Diagnosis14[i]!="Intellectual disabilities [6543]")
       {New$IntellDis[i]=0}
}
```

Clearly this is quite tedious...

I thought something like this might work:

```
IntellDis <- for (i in 1:2189){
  if(New[c(4:17)][i]=="Intellectual disabilities [6543]")
          {New$IntellDis[i]=1}
  if(New[c(4:17)][i]!="Intellectual disabilities [6543]")
          {New$IntellDis[i]=0}
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(New[c(4:17)], i) : undefined columns selected
```

Any suggestions are much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Any particular language?

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that -- R :)

Comment: For anyone who is interested, I got this figured out and thought I'd share in case someone else comes across the same issue... The above code just needed a little tweaking:
`IntellDis <- for (i in 1:nrow(New)){`
  `if("Intellectual disabilities [6543]" %in% New[i, 4:17])`
  `{New$IntellDis[i]=1}`
  `else{New$IntellDis[i]=0}`
`}`

Comment: It is amazing, no one was able to solve this issue for you in such a long time!!!